# Team Fundation Server and programing in Sharepoint

Tags: development

If it is posible to Integration programing in Sharepoint with Team Fundation Server ? Can it be made in server and trying to run projects from TFS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a SharePoint project is just a .net project so as long as your visual studio instance can get to your TFS server and you have permissions to the code base, you can check out/in code as you would with any other .net project. For SharePoint 2010 and 2007 you will need to be running the code from the server you are hitting unless you are using REST or the Client Object Model to hit the SharePoint farm.